# MySQL table reorder

Tags: mysql, sql

**I have a table like**
id - some data
1 - ...
2 - ...
4 - ...
5 - ...
8 - ...
12 - ...

The table is really long, with thousands IDs. Look at IDs, there are "empty" numbers between of them. I want to reorder all IDs to have no empty ones.

**Table should look like**
1 - ...
2 - ...
3 - ...
4 - ...
etc.

How would the query look like?

Comment: Don't do that. Don't mess with the auto-increment numbers. Leave them! What do you actually want to do?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31232740/complicated-reorder-of-mysql-tables by OP.

Answer (score 2):

I don't advocate re-numbering ids.  The id column should be the primary key for the table, and gaps don't make a difference.  If it is used for foreign key references, then you will be messing up your database.

But, you can do it as:

```
set @rn = 0;

update `table` t
    set t.id = (@rn := @rn + 1)
    order by t.id;
```