# Complicated reorder of MySQL tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

**I should do really complicated tables reorder.**

****The main table looks like:****

```
id - some data
1 - ...
2 - ...
3 - ...
6 - ...
9 - ...
12 - ...
```

As you can see, there are "empty" IDs (no 4, 5 between 3 and 6 etc).

****Table should look like****

```
id - data
1 - ...
2 - ...
3 - ...
4 - ...
5 - ...
6 - ...
7 - ...
etc (without empty IDs)
```

**Why do I want to make it:** this is a server database, includes millions IDs. The server crashes when maintaining such big numbers. If I reorder IDs and there won't be any empty ones, the MAX ID in this table will be much lower and it will prevent server from crashing.

**The most complicated thing** - this table has foreign key references (only ID column references atleast) in like 4-5 different tables.

**My thought is** - reorder main table by IDs without empty ones and create new temp table with (oldID, newID) structure and then replace oldID's with newID's in the other related tables.

Any ideas how the query would look like? It will probably take half an hour to execute that query but it's the least problem.

Comment: The size of the numbers in your `id` column is *not* causing your server to crash, unless you have *very* arcane queries.  SQL is rather agnostic as to the sizes of numbers used for ids in tables.  You should not change the ids unless you have a really good reason and know that other tables do not reference them.  Perhaps you should ask *another* question about how to fix the queries that you are using.

Comment: It's a game server written on C++ and it really has some issues when handling big ID numbers for many players. I want to make a query as I described in question and execute it once per month as a clean up.

Comment: In that case, you need to fix your C++ code.  It shouldn't be making assumptions about user ids.

Comment: Changing identifiers / **ID**s is most of the time no good idea. - Not the least, you needed to propagate the changed **ID**s consistently.  How would you time the switch-over from old to new **ID**s? And if there are external references to your **ID**s, you should no longer even think about it.

Comment: If, your application is actually having/causing the trouble, you could try to join your temp/translation table to your SQL result sets, and alias the column(s) to expose smaller values under the known name. For this to work, all new `INSERT`s would require, additions to this translation table as well. The more `INSERT`s /`UPDATE`s your application has to handle, the less likely this will be fun to do.

Comment: If really pressed hard, I'd probably think about adding **newID** columns to the respective tables, fill them according to the translation table. Then drop the old **ID** column, and rename **newID**. If you can afford some downtime... Otherwise you'd need to add a flag to your application to know from which **ID** set a particular value is coming...