# Want to improve SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called "world". It has some empty IDs:

```
id - data
1 - ...
2 - ...
(no 3,4 IDs after 2)
5 - ...
```

And I have a query to select the lowest unused ID in this table. It looks like:

```
SELECT MIN(t1.id)
FROM 
(
 SELECT 1 AS id
 UNION ALL
 SELECT id + 1
 FROM world
) t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN world t2
ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t2.id IS NULL;
```

I want to find a way how to improve this query to make it execute faster.

Comment: Is this related to your other two questions [Complicated reorder of MySQL tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31232740/complicated-reorder-of-mysql-tables) and [MySQL table reorder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31231851/mysql-table-reorder)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
select (w.id + 1)
from world w left join
     world w2
     on w.id = w2.id - 1
where w2.id is null
order by w.id
limit 1
```

This should have reasonable performance with an index on `world(id)`.

SQLFiddle for the same [SQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e2080/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the first unused ID after the first used one (i.e. it won't give you ID 1 if it's unused but will work for the rest).

```
SELECT id + 1 FROM world WHERE (id + 1) NOT IN (
    SELECT id FROM world
) ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1
```

To include ID 1 you could do a specific check first to see if it exists, or do something like:

```
SELECT IF(
    NOT EXISTS(SELECT id FROM world WHERE id = 1),
    1,
    (SELECT id + 1 FROM world WHERE (id + 1) NOT IN (
        SELECT id FROM world
    ) ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1)
) AS min_unused
```